# How to find what is causing a 502 Bad Gateway nginx Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, nginx

I'm trying to deploy my app which using nodejs and angular. Everything looks fine on

```
sudo pm2 logs.
```

[image]

I have also done

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Nginx is ok and successful.

However when I look at the error.logs from nginx directory, I have this.

[image]

I then when to this link here [Nginx error "1024 worker_connections are not enough"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56723449/nginx-error-1024-worker-connections-are-not-enough)

I changed it to 1500 worker connections and I'm still in the same spot. Is there another way around this? Please help, I have been trying to deploy this website for over a week. Thank you for your time.

Comment: have you updated ulimit value aswell?

Comment: Only the worker connections. I don't see that in the nginx.conf where I updated the worker connections.

Comment: can you post the client code too?